# Derby db: sql update the results of a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-update, derby

I have two tables:

**ELEMENT:**

```
ID (int. key)
TYPE (String)
```

**ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTES:**

```
ELEMENT_ID (int)
ATTR_NAME (String)
```

(I am ignoring the fields in my original tables which are not essential for this question)

I would like to do something like:

```
UPDATE ELEMENT e, ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTES a
SET a.ATTR_NAME='new name'
WHERE e.ID = a.ELEMENT_ID
  AND e.TYPE = 'a specific type'
  AND a.ATTR_NAME = 'old name'
```

is this possible in derby sql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [the Derby Reference Manual on the UPDATE statement](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefsqlj26498.html) the syntax is:

```
{
    UPDATE table-Name [[AS] correlation-Name]
        SET column-Name = Value
        [ , column-Name = Value} ]*
        [WHERE clause] |
    UPDATE table-Name
        SET column-Name = Value
        [ , column-Name = Value ]*
        WHERE CURRENT OF
}
```

So no, you cannot execute a query as in your question. You would need to modify it a bit like:

```
UPDATE ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTES a
SET a.ATTR_NAME='new name'
WHERE a.ATTR_NAME = 'old name'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM ELEMENT e 
            WHERE a.ELEMENT_ID = e.ID AND e.TYPE = 'a specific type')
```

Answer (score 2):

For record:
I did it. The select clause has to return only one result per row to be updated, so:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE1 A SET 
    A.FIELD1 = (SELECT b.FIELD2 
                FROM MY_OTHERTABLE B 
                WHERE (A.FIELD3= B.FIELD3) AND (A.FIELD4= B.FIELD4));
```

Comment: Hi Jose, and thank you for contributing! I want to point out a couple of things about this answer: First, the update statement would update every row in MY_TABLE1 instead of a specific record, which is what the question was asking. Second, this question was asked quite a long time ago and already has a good answer. Please check out some of the more recent questions, and keep contributing! :-)